# MVC 5 MultiThreading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to setup multithreading in a .NET MVC application.  I am processing a large amount of data, so my hope is if I split it into multiple threads I can speed up the processing time.  The method isn't waiting for the tasks to complete though before it runs the data, so it's currently returning an empty list.  I want to wait for all of the tasks to be completed before it returns the final result.

If there's a better way to this I'm loading a datatable and basically want to take the `roster` variable and run the `CheckCompliance` method for each individual.  Without multithreading the page could take minutes to load, I'm wanting the page to load with almost no delay.

```
public async Task<Tuple<List<RosterListing>, int, int>> Search(int employerId, DataTableAjaxPostModel model)
{
    List<RosterListing> roster = _service.Search(employerId, searchBy, columnSearches, take, skip, sortBy, sortDir, out int filteredResultsCount, out int totalResultsCount);
    IEnumerable<Mandate> enforcedMandates = _mandateService.GetEnforcedMandates();
    IEnumerable<IndividualMandateData> individualMandateData = _individualMandateDataService.GetAllForPtbIds(roster.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.PtbId)));

    List<RosterListing> newRoster = new List<RosterListing>();

    // Split main list into sections for multithreading
    List<List<RosterListing>> chunks = roster.ChunkBy(5);

    var tasks = new List<Task<List<RosterListing>>>();
    foreach (var chunk in chunks)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            List<RosterListing> updatedRoster = new List<RosterListing>();
            updatedRoster.AddRange(await CheckCompliance(chunk, enforcedMandates, individualMandateData));

            return updatedRoster;
        }));
    }

    var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        
    if (results.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        foreach (var result in results.Result)
        {
            newRoster.AddRange(result);
        }
    }
    
    // This doesn't wait until all tasks are complete
    return await Task.Run(() => Tuple.Create(newRoster, filteredResultsCount, totalResultsCount));
}


private async Task<List<RosterListing>> CheckCompliance(List<RosterListing> roster, IEnumerable<Mandate> enforcedMandates, IEnumerable<IndividualMandateData> individualMandateData)
{
    foreach (var officer in roster)
    {
        foreach (var mandate in enforcedMandates)
        {

            IndividualMandateData data = individualMandateData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MandateId == mandate.MandateId && x.PtbId == Convert.ToInt32(officer.PtbId));

            if (data == null)
            {
                officer.IsInCompliance = false;
                break;
            }


            if (mandate.MandateRequirementUnit == "Course")
            {
                if (data.HoursAttended < 0)
                {
                    officer.IsInCompliance = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (data.HoursAttended < mandate.Requirement)
                {
                    officer.IsInCompliance = false;
                    break;
                }

            }

            officer.IsInCompliance = true;
        }
    }

    return await Task.Run(() => roster);
}
```

Comment: `CheckCompliance` doesn't do anything in parallel. Everything runs on the calling thread until `await Task.Run(() => roster)` returns the already calculated `roster`. Instead of creating individual tasks, it's better to use PLINQ or Parallel.ForEach and have *them* take care of partitioning, sorting, filtering etc.

Comment: There may not be any need for parallelism though. Using a more efficient algorithm can result in orders of magnitude better performance. Instead of searching `individualMandateData` for example, there could be a HashSet or Dictionary using a ValueTuple with `MandateId` and `PtbId` as keys

Comment: What do `_service.Search`, `_mandateService.GetEnforcedMandates` and `_individualMandateDataService.GetAllForPtbIds` do? If they load data from the same database, a *far* faster option is to use a query or view to JOIN between the tables and return the necessary data, or make the necessary UPDATEs. A database server has far CPU and RAM available than any web server. Using indexes, it will have far less work to do than the web server too. If everything can be done in a single UPDATE, no data will have to travel to the client and back

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  `GetEnforcedMandates` returns a View that returns all of the mandates in the database (it's a separate database than the one this application is in).  The `GetAllForPTBIds` have a list of all of the courses and number of hours per mandate.  I initially tried to calculate `InCompliance` in the SQL View, but the query would take 30 minutes to load, so I was trying to speed it up in code.

Comment: You almost never want to use parallelism or `Task.Run` in ASP.NET. Proper solutions include db optimization and cachine.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you show me how to update the code to PLINQ? I tried to do it but initially I was getting a null error message and now since I cancelled the debugging I'm getting an error `The underlying provider failed to open`

Comment: @StephenCleary I think part of the issue is that I'm doing calculations on two separate databases (same server) so I can't create indexed views.  I originally attempted to check compliance in a view but it was just as slow

Comment: @Andrew you should create a separate reporting database then. If you need 30 minutes to process the data, how can you be sure the HTTP request won't time out? How many rows are there anyway?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm sure the HTTP request would time out, that was just running the query directly in the database.  I didn't attempt to integrate that into the web app.  That was only processing 13,240 records.  It takes about a minute and a half to process a roster with 10 records.  Here is how I was trying to write the query directly in SQL Server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75151374/cross-apply-takes-a-while-to-load

Comment: 13K rows is no data at all. 13K rows probably fit in the CPU's cache. If that takes 30 minutes something is very, very wrong with the query.  If there were 13M rows that all had to be processed, then maybe

Comment: I agree, 13k is nothing.  I should clarify 13k is the number of individuals (end result). Each individual is joining to a View that contains 307k records and it has to go through each record in the View and check to see if they're in compliance.